# What cookie will browser send in XHR request if response comes in the meantime?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

If I use javascript to create XHR request. And the entire code from `var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();` to `myRequest.send()` will be synchronous. And the response from another XHR request with different cookie will return somewhere between creating the XHR request and sending it. What cookies will my new XHR request has? The one that was here before creating myRequest or the one that was in response?

Now the exactly same question, except the code between `var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();` and `myRequest.send()` will be asynchronous.